# Want to use a cell to get a limit number

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

Here is my query. I want `"select * limit 5")` the 5 to come from a cell. How do I do that?

`=ArrayFormula(AVERAGE(QUERY(SORT(Tabell!D4:D33,ROW(Tabell!D4:D33)*ISNUMBER(Tabell!D4:D33),0),"select * limit 5")))`

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. It's not clear what is your question about. Please add some sample data input and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following, assuming the limit is on cell A1

```
=QUERY(SORT(Tabell!D4:D33,ROW(Tabell!D4:D33)*ISNUMBER(Tabell!D4:D33),0),"select * limit " & A1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(AVERAGE(QUERY(SORT(Tabell!D4:D33,ROW(Tabell!D4:D33)*ISNUMBER(Tabell!D4:D33),0),"select * limit "&D2&"")))
```

*(where `D2` is the cell containing `5`)*

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.